# erro com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estou tendo um erro com o bootstrap, o carousel está funcionando certinho mas a imagem que deveria pegar todo o espaçamento do box está minimizada e o hover não está centralizando na imagem, sem o link do bootstrap funciona tudo certo mas eu preciso atualizar esse código pra poder utilizar o link e não estou conseguindo, alguém pode me dar uma idéia do que fazer?

assim que deveria ficar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.box14{position:relative}
.box15,.box17,.box18{box-shadow:0 0 5px #7e7d7d;text-align:center}
.box14:before{content:"";width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;transition:all .35s ease 0s}
.box14:hover:before{opacity:1}
.box14 img{width:100%;height:auto}
.box14 .box-content{width:90%;height:90%;position:absolute;top:5%;left:5%}
.box14 .box-content:after,.box14 .box-content:before{content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;opacity:0;transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14 .box-content:before{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);border-top:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);transform:scale(0,1);transform-origin:0 0 0}
.box14 .box-content:after{border-left:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);transform:scale(1,0);transform-origin:100% 0 0}
.box14:hover .box-content:after,.box14:hover .box-content:before{opacity:1;transform:scale(1);transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .title{font-size:21px;font-weight:700;color:#fff;margin:15px 0;opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-50px,0);transition:transform .5s ease 0s}
.box14:hover .title{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
.box14 .post{font-size:14px;color:#fff;padding:10px;background:#a2c270;opacity:0;border-radius:0 19px;transform:translate3d(0,-50px,0);transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14 .icon,.box15 .icon{padding:0;list-style:none}
.box14:hover .post{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .icon{width:100%;margin:0;position:absolute;bottom:-10px;left:0;opacity:0;z-index:1;transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14:hover .icon{bottom:20px;opacity:1;transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .icon li a{display:block;width:40px;height:40px;line-height:40px;border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:0 16px;font-size:14px;color:#fff;margin-right:5px;transition:all .4s ease 0s}
.box14 .icon li a:hover{background:#a2c270;border-color:#a2c270}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){.box14{margin-bottom:30px}
}

.icon-cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 10000px;
          perspective: 10000px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.icon-cards__content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
          transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-animation: carousel 15s infinite cubic-bezier(0.005, 0.625, 0.365, 0.840) forwards;
          animation: carousel 15s infinite cubic-bezier(0.005, 0.625, 0.365, 0.840) forwards;
}
.icon-cards__item {
  border: 1px solid #a2c270;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(1) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(300px);
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(2) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(300px);
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(3) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(300px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes carousel {
  0%,  17.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  }
  27.5%, 45% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
  }
  55%, 72.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
  }
  82.5%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes carousel {
  0%,  17.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  }
  27.5%, 45% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
  }
  55%, 72.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
  }
  82.5%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--Link CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

<!----------------------carousel cards-------------------------->
<figure class="icon-cards mt-5">
  <div class="icon-cards__content">
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content mt-5" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content mt-5" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content mt-5" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>

<!--JavaScript / jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está deixando as imagens menores são as classes `col-md-4` e `col-sm-6`, o que, pela estrutura das divs, me parecem desnecessárias.

Outra classe que está bugando a div escura no hover é a `mt-5`, que aplica uma margem superior extra ao elemento fazendo ele ficar fora da div.

Retire essas classes e tudo fica no lugar:

```css
.box14{position:relative}
.box15,.box17,.box18{box-shadow:0 0 5px #7e7d7d;text-align:center}
.box14:before{content:"";width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;transition:all .35s ease 0s}
.box14:hover:before{opacity:1}
.box14 img{width:100%;height:auto}
.box14 .box-content{width:90%;height:90%;position:absolute;top:5%;left:5%}
.box14 .box-content:after,.box14 .box-content:before{content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;opacity:0;transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14 .box-content:before{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);border-top:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);transform:scale(0,1);transform-origin:0 0 0}
.box14 .box-content:after{border-left:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);transform:scale(1,0);transform-origin:100% 0 0}
.box14:hover .box-content:after,.box14:hover .box-content:before{opacity:1;transform:scale(1);transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .title{font-size:21px;font-weight:700;color:#fff;margin:15px 0;opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-50px,0);transition:transform .5s ease 0s}
.box14:hover .title{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
.box14 .post{font-size:14px;color:#fff;padding:10px;background:#a2c270;opacity:0;border-radius:0 19px;transform:translate3d(0,-50px,0);transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14 .icon,.box15 .icon{padding:0;list-style:none}
.box14:hover .post{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .icon{width:100%;margin:0;position:absolute;bottom:-10px;left:0;opacity:0;z-index:1;transition:all .7s ease 0s}
.box14:hover .icon{bottom:20px;opacity:1;transition-delay:.15s}
.box14 .icon li a{display:block;width:40px;height:40px;line-height:40px;border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:0 16px;font-size:14px;color:#fff;margin-right:5px;transition:all .4s ease 0s}
.box14 .icon li a:hover{background:#a2c270;border-color:#a2c270}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){.box14{margin-bottom:30px}
}

.icon-cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 10000px;
          perspective: 10000px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.icon-cards__content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
          transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-animation: carousel 15s infinite cubic-bezier(0.005, 0.625, 0.365, 0.840) forwards;
          animation: carousel 15s infinite cubic-bezier(0.005, 0.625, 0.365, 0.840) forwards;
}
.icon-cards__item {
  border: 1px solid #a2c270;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(1) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(300px);
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(2) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(300px);
}
.icon-cards__item:nth-child(3) {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(83, 40%, 60%, 0.60), hsla(162, 33%, 61%, 0.60))!important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(300px);
          transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(300px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes carousel {
  0%,  17.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  }
  27.5%, 45% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
  }
  55%, 72.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
  }
  82.5%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes carousel {
  0%,  17.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(0);
  }
  27.5%, 45% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-120deg);
  }
  55%, 72.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-240deg);
  }
  82.5%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
            transform: translateZ(-182px) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--Link CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

<!----------------------carousel cards-------------------------->
<figure class="icon-cards mt-5">
  <div class="icon-cards__content">
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div>
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div>
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-cards__item">
      <div>
        <div class="box14">
            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/hover-effect/demo105/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="box-content" align="center">
                <h3 class="title">Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
                <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>

<!--JavaScript / jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```